# Is it possible to pass both an object and additional parameters with a method?

Tags: javascript

I have a linear gauge that produces some labels based on values in the object passed as a parameter like this:
function createGauges(conveyanceId, maxDepthRange) {

```
$("#depthBar-" + conveyanceId).kendoLinearGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: 0,
        shape: "arrow",
        color: "transparent",
        start: 0,
        reverse: true
    },
    scale: {
        majorUnit: 800,
        minorUnit: 400,
        min: 0,
        max: maxDepthRange,
        labels: {
            template: getLabel
        },
        vertical: false,
        reverse: false,
        ranges: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 0,
            color: "dodgerblue"
        }
        ]
    }
});
```

Currently, the getLabel-method is looking like this:

```
function getLabel(e) {
    if (e.value === 12000) {
        return e.value;
    }
    else if (e.value === 0) {
        return e.value;
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

As it stands, this works fine as the `max: maxDepthRange` actually is 12000 (fetched from database). But, whenever the value of maxDepthRange changes from 12000, I'd like the getLabel-method to handle this, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass along an additional parameter.
This is what I've tried, having set the getLabel-call to `getLabel(e, maxDepthRange)`:

```
function getLabel(e, maxDepthVal) {
    if (e.value === maxDepthVal) {
        return e.value;
    }
    else if (e.value === 0) {
        return e.value;
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the code to this should work:

```
labels: {
        template: function(e) { return getLabel(e, 12000); } // maxDepthVal as 2nd param
    },
```

Comment: Somehow (not sure if this is the component or the getLabel function) this does not work properly. If the maxDepthVal parameter is something other than 12000, 10000, 9000 etc. (numbers dividable by 2), like 9001, it does not display. However, if I change min value to 1, and max value to 9001 it displays.

Comment: @NicklasWinger You might need to round the numbers? What kind of values are passed in as e.value?

Comment: 9229,00 is one example. Rounding off decimals you mean? Strange that the number 12000,00 works :S